# Assigning value to an array in nested for loop

Tags: list-manipulation

I want to write a code like

```
X={};  
index=1;  
max=3;  
For[i=1,i<=2,i++,  
For[j=1,j<=2,j++,  
X[[index]]=i*j;  
index++  
]  
]
```

But I am not getting correct result. Can anyone please help

Comment: Presumably, you want either `x=Array[#1*#2 &, {3, 3}] // Flatten` or `x=Table[i*j, {i, 3}, {j, 3}] // Flatten`

Comment: For sure, you [don't want to use the `For` loop](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica).

Comment: I would use the `Table` solution proposed by @bob-hanlon

Comment: Or `Flatten@KroneckerProduct[#, #]&@Range@3`

Answer (score 3):

Summary of methods. (Add yours if you have one not already here.)

Bob Hanlon

```
 Array[#1*#2 &, {3, 3}] // Flatten 
 Table[i*j, {i, 3}, {j, 3}] // Flatten
```

Simon Rochester

```
KroneckerProduct @@ Range[{3, 3}] // Flatten
Range[3] Range[{3, 3, 3}] // Flatten
Accumulate /@ Transpose@Range@ConstantArray[3, 3] // Flatten
```

m_goldberg

```
Range[3] ConstantArray[Range[3], 3] // Flatten
```